# Is JSF/JSP the only choice if I use the Java EE to develop my site?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

I am studying Java EE technology. I noticed that JSF is an available choice for developing web application. But is it the only choice if I wanna use Java EE tech?

Comment: There are loads of technologies you can use see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_EE_version_history#Java_EE_6_.28Dec_10.2C_2009.29 Its upto you what you want to use.

Comment: As i know not only but at least most efficient and logical way to do it, what a problem with that?

Comment: No, you can use primefaces, jsf, spring framework, play framework, struts 2 etc.

Answer (score 2):

You have numerous Choices when it comes to choosing Web Application Frameworks, depending upon your choice you select one.

You can go for no framework too, but it would be like ending up with complex designs that even yourself won't be able to understand later.

JSF, Netty, Seam, Sitemesh, Spark, Spring MVC, Stripes, Struts, VRaptor, Wicket are some of the examples you can go for.

With JSF, you have navigational framework, MVC framework and RichFaces/IceFaces for front-end. With others, you have navigation and mvc too, and you can use jQuery for front-end.

When it comes to using Databases, transactions, etc. You will have to make another choice between persistence implementations i.e. JPA, EJB3.0 JPA Implementation, Hibernate, Spring with Hibernate and MVC and IoC.

so.. long story short, you need to read.

Answer (score 1):

JSF is only one of the Front-End solutions. There are too many to enumerate.
There are differences between they, advantages and disadvantages.

Other Javascript based UI is GWT.

You can have non Javascript based ones: JSP or even just servlet for a "Hello word"

You can use frameworks which will have the MVC pattern embedded: Struts, Spring.

For start learning: I would choose a framework free implementation - to learn what is implemented later in different frameworks. Just a plain JSP pages written manually.

Later on production, bigger J2EE, which will require more team members, higher speed of development, you can choose a framework, which the project needs and most of developers know.